# Problem PC stopped seeing S4

Tags: connection-issues

My S4 has suddenly stopped to connect to any computer. I tried with 3 different cables and 2 PC's with win7. I can't see it as a hard-drive. I can't see it in the device manager either (should I)?
Any help would be welcome.
Many thanks!

Comment: What about connecting with Kies? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the drivers from Samsung and download and install then again on your PC this seems to be an driver problem. If this not resolve your problem come back and I can suggest other options.

Does your phone recharge when plugged in?

Any sound on your PC when you connect or any notification on your phone about being connected via USB?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
The phone is charging and there is a beep when I connect it to the pc. I tried to connect it to other pc's where no Android were ever connected and I couldn't see it ether. Tried to reinstall the driver but nothing yet.